# Improve MySQL Query to fetch records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called progress which stores different type of progress for both client and member;

[image]

I have a MYSQL Query, which is suppose to get progress data both from the client to member and member to client. Currently I have a queries in the following way;

```
SELECT * 
FROM progress
WHERE (client = 'XXXX' AND member = 'YYYY') 
    OR (client = 'YYYY' AND member = 'XXXX')
```

it gets me the result I want, but how can I improve this query in terms of the way it is written.

Please help, any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks fine to me. It can't get much simpler.

Comment: I think he actually meant to swap the two roles, and copied it wrong.

Comment: Don't use `'XXXX'` if `XXXX` is a number.

Comment: sorry for the mistake. I fixed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Barmar said in the comments `It can't get much simpler` but you have some options as per your question of WRITING this query:

You can use a UNION

```
select * from progress where (client = 'xxxx' and member = 'yyyy') 
 union all
select * from progress where (client = 'yyyy' and member = 'xxxx')
```

You can use `IN` statements

```
select * from progress
 where (client) in ('XXXX','YYYY')
   and (member) in ('YYYY','XXXX');
```

And you can use your own solution.

**Edit**

Forgot to add the fiddle i did: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74e6ec/7

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Union.

```
SELECT * FROM progress WHERE (client = 'XXXX' AND member = 'YYYY') 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM progress WHERE (client = 'YYYY' AND member = 'XXXX')
```

Comment: Why? Justify, please.

Comment: UNION ALL is the right choice since I doubt there will be duplicates.